# The name of the enclosing class is 'MultipartRequestMultipartFile'

Tags: flutter, dart, http

package:http/src/multipart_file.dart: Context: The name of the enclosing class is 'MultipartRequestMultipartFile'.
../…/src/multipart_file.dart:1

: Error: Type 'MultipartFile' not found.
../…/src/multipart_file.dart:92

```
  static Future<MultipartFile> fromPath(String field, String filePath,


                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

: Error: Type 'MultipartFile' not found.
../…/src/multipart_request.dart:133

```
  String _headerForFile(MultipartFile file) {


                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

: Error: Type 'MultipartFile' not found.
../…/src/multipart_file_io.dart:13

```
Future<MultipartFile> multipartFileFromPath(String field, String filePath,


       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

: Error: 'MultipartFile' isn't a type.
../…/src/multipart_request.dart:46

```
  final files = <MultipartFile>[];


                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

: Error: Method not found: 'MultipartFile'.
../…/src/multipart_file.dart:63

```
    return MultipartFile(field, stream, value.length,


           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

: Error: Undefined name 'MultipartFile'.
../…/src/multipart_file.dart:79

```
    return MultipartFile.fromBytes(field, encoding.encode(value),


           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

: Error: A value of type 'double' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int'.
../…/src/multipart_request.dart:67

```
      length += '--'.length +


             ^
```

: Error: 'MultipartFile' isn't a type.
../…/src/multipart_request.dart:133

```
  String _headerForFile(MultipartFile file) {


                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

: Error: Method not found: 'MultipartFile'.
../…/src/multipart_file_io.dart:19

```
  return MultipartFile(field, stream, length,


         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^


Failed to package /Users/bookwarm/Programming/Flutter/chatApp.


Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code


note: Using new build system


note: Planning


note: Build preparation complete


note: Building targets in dependency order


/Users/bookwarm/Programming/Flutter/chatApp/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.2.99. (in target 'libPhoneNumber-iOS' from project 'Pods')


Result bundle written to path:


    /var/folders/cz/5ph142ld41dfggj5brlf41h00000gn/T/flutter_tools.E4o277/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirVbiyqD/temporary_xcresult_bundle
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

just delete
/Users/xxxxxxx/development/tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/
and run flutter packages get again on your project.